# How to set last-modified header in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, header

I need to set the last-modified header to last hour or day etc.. but i can't figure it, if anybody has a solution please help me.

Edited:
I can add using this PHP code but i need to use on Nginx configuration. Any Idea?

```
// Last Modified
$time = time() - 60; // or filemtime($fn), etc
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $time).' GMT');
```

Comment: Are we talking about assets like images and js or full php rendered pages?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady  thanks for the question, full php rendered pages.